# Arquillian Integraiton tests failing when upgrading to Wildfly 26.1.3.Final with JakartaEE9

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian

We had to upgrade an application from wildfly 26.0.1.Final to 26.1.3.Final. As there was an upgrade from JakartaEE8 to JakartaEE9 with this aswell there where problems with the primefaces UI (e.g. pagination not working). We updated the primefaces dependency to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.0-RC2</version>
  <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```

and now everything works fine besides our arquillian integration tests.

We use org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools:26.1.3.Final and arquillian comes with the version 1.6.0. From what i read we should upgrade arquillian to 1.8.0 to solve the issue but i am not able to find a corresponding wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools/wildfly-jakartaee9-with-tools nor am i able to overwrite to arquillian 1.8.0. When i overwrite it i always get this constellation in dependency:tree which makes no sense to me:

```
INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.8.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.6.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.6.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.6.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.6.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-spi:jar:1.6.0.Final:test
```

Exclusions dont solve this problem either.

Comment: WildFly 26 is Jakarta EE 8 not 9 or 10. You should either move to Jakarta EE 10 or stay on 8  as Jakarta EE9 didn't bring any real change (apart from the prefix change).

Comment: Well i wish i had the choice here but the app server is configured with company standard and the applications have to run with Wildfly 26.1.3.Final using JakartaEE9 :/

Comment: Sorry but WildFly 26.1.3 wasn't released with JakartaEE 9 support (except if you are using preview which was meant to prepare the transition to 10).